# Shutdown task through an abstract class javafx

Tags: java, javafx, task

Here is my question. I can't figure out about shutdown a task through another class. I have an Abstract Class which fire method for several classes that are inherited. This method will run a task and for different reasons, users will probably enable to stop this task if they need to change a parameter or something like that. see snippets bellow:

```
public interface Service {

void runThread();

void stopThread();
```

}

here is the class implementation:

```
public class ServiceImpl extends AbstractService implements Service {

@Override
public void runThread() {
    System.out.println("run thread: impl class");
    super.run();
}

@Override
public void stopThread() {
    System.out.println("stop Thread");
    System.out.println("Thread is shutdown: " + super.exec.isShutdown());
    super.exec.shutdownNow();
    System.out.println("Thread is shutdown: " + super.exec.isShutdown());
}
```

}

And the abstract class which will fire the super.run() method:

```
public abstract class AbstractService {

protected ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public AbstractService() {
    super();
}

protected void run() {
    System.out.println("run thread: abstract class");

    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                updateMessage("Hello World: " + i);
            }

            updateMessage("done");
            return null;
        }

    };

    task.setOnRunning(s -> {
        Main.label.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
    });

    task.setOnSucceeded(s -> {
        Main.label.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
    });

    exec.submit(task);
}
```

}

As it is, it works and if the user click on the button stop, the exec.shutdownnow() will be fired and the count in the loop will be stopped.

But my question is I want to seperate in a another class the **stopThread()** method in order to command the stop action as a master call. Because the **ServiceImpl** is just an example of one class whose inherit from abstract class, if I have 6 or 10 classes which inherit from abstract class, I don't want to implement for each **ServiceImpl** a **stopThread()** method. So I tried and the result is pretty weird because my "master class -> StopServiceImpl" fire the **stopThread()** method, the state of super.exec passing through Thread is shutdown: false and Thread is shutdown: true but the count in the abstract class loop still counting ...

Is there a possibility to implement that or should I duplicate the code in each ServiceImpl to stop the task?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. I'm also not sure if I look at the code what you are trying to do? Are you making an alternative for JavaFX's [`ScheduledService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html)? Are you aware that by using static references to your UI elements you'll paving future problems?

Comment: No I am not trying to make an alternative of ´ScheduledService´ but I just want to access from the UI (as a button) the task to stop. I know the issue about static UI elements but this is the simplest way to access from a distant class

Answer (score 0):

If you submit a task to a scheduler you get a `Future<>` in back. A `Future<>` can be cancelled by calling [`cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)).

```
Future<?> future = scheduler.submit(task);
...
future.cancel(true); // Your task needs to check the 'interrupt' otherwise it'll just finish anyway.
```